# trigger and .load new content from inside of already .loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-load

im trying to .load some content which is triggered by clicking an  tag with an id# which is already inside of loaded content.

At the moment im using this (bellow) to load the content in the first place, run a nivo slider and then the bit im having trouble with trying to load in the new content

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#pegasus-tile, #o-w").click(function(){
    $("#proj-content").load("projects/pegasus.html", function(){

        $('<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"></div>');
        $('#slider').nivoSlider({effect: 'sliceUpDown'}),

    $("#next-pegasus").click(function(){
        $("#proj-content").load("projects/bg-app.html");        

        });
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: not as yet, i implemented both of the awnsers but they didnt seem to work, im about to build it into a jsfiddle, perhaps other things running on the site its on are restricting it. So ill build a clean version to test it on

Comment: ok, post the fiddle if you want me to have a look at it

Comment: in making the fiddle ive come across a problem, i have to request the loaded content from the original site, but this dosnt seem to want to work. If i just have the content hidden on the page it wont work in the same manor ? Any idea whats the best way to handle this, calling content from external sites ? (the fiddle so far  The fiddle that ive made so far http://jsfiddle.net/DXdN6/ )

Comment: Yeah I can see where that would be a problem :-)

Comment: I suggest taking the original function, stripping it down to doing just one thing and debugging it to see what's going on behind the scenes and then add to it one more piece at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the .live() function.

Your code doesn't work, because the element with id next-pegasus is dynamically added and the default .click()-Listener cant "see" this element.
To get it work, implement the click-Listener for the #next-pegasus element like this:

```
$('#next-pegasus').live('click', function() {
    // do the same stuff here ...
});
```

Edit:

Use the .on()-function instead, because the .live() is deprecated.

Comment: Do not use `.live` , it has been deprecated, use `.on`

Comment: @CD smith, thanks, i was just reading on the jquery site "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()." just looking at your post above, could you explain the differences between .on and .empty ?

Comment: `.empty` empties out the contents of the element before the next `.load` so if there is text in that element, the `.empty` ensures the contents are removed http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Answer (score 1):

Run a `.empty` before the next `.load`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pegasus-tile, #o-w").click(function(){
        $("#proj-content").empty().load("projects/pegasus.html", function(){
            $('<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"></div>');
            $('#slider').nivoSlider({effect: 'sliceUpDown'}),
    $("#next-pegasus").click(function(){
        $("#proj-content").empty().load("projects/bg-app.html");        

        });
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: Finaly got it working ! Not sure what it was but i rebuilt from scratch and used code as above, because of the way its works ie empties then loads there is a "jump" as you get the flash of emptied div before the new one. Using .on() fixes this as is suppose it makes that dynamcly added elements visable in a different way ?